# react-native init fails on device in v0.30.0

Tags: react-native

Everything was going swimmingly until 0.30.0 rolled in. You could just go to AppDelegate.m and put in your IP address, and 'bam!' It worked!

No more. I tried changing 'localhost' in RCTWebSocketExecutor.m, I tried the silver bullet and non-silver-bullet approach to editing info.plist, re: App Transport Security Settings, I even sacrificed a ring-tailed possum to RCTBridgeToTheGods.m, nothing.

It works in the simulator, but not on my device. Again, it was working on my device a version ago, so I think I have everything set up that ... well, would be set up to make it work in 0.29.0-land.

The behavior goes: the xib launch screen launches, and I can even get my own launch screen image set to work, but then I hit a white screen with just a status bar, and nothing else. To the output is logged: 2016-07-26 15:43:37.240 [warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:52] Sending 'websocketFailed' with no listeners registered.

I looked through every post tagged react-native since the release of 0.30.0, and there were no answers. I asked Reactiflux, but they seem to be tired of helping people get up and running. If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think it was caused by the new project template, specifically `AppDelegate.m`. I was able to load the app but only with a static JS bundle. I commented out the following line:

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

And replaced it with the line from the old project template:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://[your IP]:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

I still had to Allow arbitary loads in `Info.plist` but those two changes solved the problem for me.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to fix it, there might be a new way of doing things that nobody mentioned in the docs or this is an actual issue.